# clojureql select between two dates

Tags: clojure, clojureql

How would I use clojureql to select between two dates? Hopefully something like this:

```
@(-> (table :abc)
     (select (where (between d1 d2))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `BETWEEN`, and while you might be tempted to use Lisp-y multiple-argument `<`, that does not work either:

```
;; invalid SQL output
hello-cql.core> (select (table :abc) (where (< 10 :a 20)))
SELECT abc.* FROM abc WHERE (10 < a < 20)

;; valid SQL output
hello-cql.core> (select (table :abc) (where (and (< 10 :a) (< :a 20))))
SELECT abc.* FROM abc WHERE ((10 < a) AND (a < 20))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own `between`

```
(defmacro between
  [x min max]
  `(and (< ~min ~x) (< ~x ~max)))
```

This will be compatible with ClojureQL.